# Is it possible to use Azure AD on Ubuntu for connecting to Azure SQL using sqlalchemy and Python?

Tags: ubuntu, sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

Is it possible to use Azure AD on Ubuntu for connecting to Azure SQL?

That is, it is possible to use **trusted_connection=True** in sqlalchemy in Python?

```
# Creating engine
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://*server_name*/*database_name*?trusted_connection=yes')
```

On Azure you can create a linux VM with a **managed identity** which allows you to connect to Azure services using Azure AD. In their documentation I can find [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) of how to connect to various Azure services using this, however, I see no examples of connecting to a Azure SQL database.

The closest thing I can find is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-auth-overview?view=sql-server-ver15), which is horribly convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a doc - [Tutorial: Use a Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql), you need to get the access token with the MSI and use the token to call Azure SQL.

However, it looks like the doc is for Windows VM from the doc structure, I am not sure if it is suitable for Linux VM, you can have a try. If not work, it indicates not support the Linux VM.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I have gone over the Azure documentation, and I have only found solutions for windows VMs as in your reference. The only solutions I have found for using Managed Indetities with Azure is for connecting to Azure Storage accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only option currently available (Jan 2020) to use a managed identity is to use the .NET libraries in System.Data.SqlClient or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. The good news is they are cross platform so you can call them from Linux however to bridge the Python gap you will need to call the .NET libraries from Python.

First to get started on using the .NET Core runtime on Linux.

The key is to use the access token to create your connection string.

```
var conn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();
conn.AccessToken = (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

See full tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

Alternatively you can use the System.Data.SqlClient object or the new cross platform Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to achieve something similar.

```powershell
Write-Verbose "Create SQL connectionstring"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$DatabaseName = 'Master'
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServerName.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=$DatabaseName;Connect Timeout=30"
$conn.AccessToken = $($SPNToken)
$conn

Write-Verbose "Connect to database and execute SQL script"
$conn.Open() 
$query = 'select @@version'
$command = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $conn)     
$Result = $command.ExecuteScalar()
$Result
$conn.Close()
```

The above example is using the cross platform .NET core libraries. To call them from Python one can try to use the pythonnet library.

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It looks like you have written it in Java, while I was looking for a solution in Python.

From what I can read you get an access token through a rest call to the server, and then use that for making your calls using some Sql package in Java. Is this also possible using a SQL package in python?

Comment: Apologies I missed the part about Python. The code sample above was using the cross platform PowerShell Core and .Net Core libraries. I haven't tried this but I believe a way forward is to use the Python for .NET library.

Comment: Hey Merill I will grant you the 50 points, but as this is a work around, where one has to convert data back and forth between Java and Python to make it work, I will not accept it an the answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks! Let's hope we get a better way to do this soon.