# Using Azure managed Identities to access Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

Is there a way to use Azure managed identities with Linux VMs to access Azure SQL DB?  All I could find is this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql which specifically speaks to Windows VMs. Is there a documented step-by-step approach for a Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL access using Managed Identity from Linux webapp is supported. The [Use a Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access Azure SQL tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql) is pretty much applicable to Linux, just dismiss the code sample and use something like this:

```cs
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

using
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")) {
 AccessToken = accessToken
};
using
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@VERSION", sqlConnection);
await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
var version = (string) await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync();
```

Full code available [here](https://github.com/alfredorevilla-at-whoiam/webapi-azure-ad-managed-identity-with-sql), just replace the connection string with yours.

Comment: Thank you for the response Alfredo.
Comparing your code to the Access data step for the Windows VM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql where is the Azure SQL servername specified. Or is it not necessary in your code?

Comment: @Nana it is. In my code all the connection string is retrieved from the configuration and set in the SqlConnection constructor: `new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))`. Check the `appsettings.json` file for a "Default" named connection string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the managed identity does not support for Linux VMs to access Azure SQL DB.

There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59451015/13308381). And there is a workaround which uses the cross-platform .NET core libraries, you could refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637491/13308381).

Comment: Thank you for the response Pamela

Comment: Hi Pamela. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Alfredo-MSFTIdentity Maybe I misunderstand it because I cannot find the official doc about it. Thanks for your answer.