# Access Azure SQL Database from Azure AppService via Managed Identity on different Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-managed-identity

Is it possible to access Azure SQL Database on one subscription from Azure AppService hosted on a different subscription via Managed Identity?

I followed the steps below, which has no example on different subscription.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#grant-permissions-to-managed-identity

Other links
[Using Azure managed Identities to access Azure SQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003073/using-azure-managed-identities-to-access-azure-sql-db)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql

**Update**

How to reference `idenity-name` when it is in a different subscription? shown on the link above
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#grant-permissions-to-managed-identity

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? The name should be unique in that AAD tenant

Answer (score 0):

As long as both, AppService as well as SQL DB, live in the same AAD tenant then, yes, this should be possible